# Why is rtrim removing more characters, and giving weird output?

Tags: php, character-trimming

I am trying to remove last few characters from the `string` using `rtrim`.

i have string `"Scryed (download torrent) - TPB"`

i want output string `"Scryed"`

e.g.

```
$title_t = "Scryed (download torrent) - TPB";

echo ($title_t)  ;
echo "\n";
$title =  ( rtrim ($title_t, "(download torrent) - TPB") );

echo ($title)  ;
```

gives

```
Scryed (download torrent) - TPB
Scry
```

Why is that ? 
expected output is

```
Scryed (download torrent) - TPB
Scryed
```

Comment: `rtrim()` - Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the end of a string. So `trim('abcccd', 'c')` would produce `abd`

Comment: `str_replace()` or regex would better suit.

Comment: but what if using str_replace and string is (download torrent) - TPB (download torrent) - TPB

Comment: is there something str_replace from right ? and once.

Comment: Up-voted because a list of strings (instead of a *set* string) is *not* clarified by the official documentation on php.net as late as Feb 2, 2019. -_-

Answer (score 7):

It's because `rtrim`'s second parameter is **list** of characters. Not a string to be trimmed! You should use a `substr` or `str_replace`:

```
$title =  substr($title_t, 0, strlen($title_t) - strlen("(download torrent) - TPB"));
```

or

```
$title = str_replace("(download torrent) - TPB", "" , $title_t);
```

Comment: it should be     $title = str_replace("(download torrent) - TPB", "" , $title_t);