# PHP trim inappropriate stripping

Tags: php, replace

How do I stop PHP from outputting "vega" when it should be outputting "vegas" using the following code?

```
<?php
$file = 'vegas.css';
echo rtrim($file,'.css');
//Wrong/current echo/output: vega
//Desired echo: vegas
?>
```

Comment: `echo implode('', explode('.css', $file));` ?

Comment: or `echo explode('.css', $file)[0];`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46307527/why-is-rtrim-removing-more-characters-and-giving-weird-output/46307606

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP, get file name without file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183486/php-get-file-name-without-file-extension)

Comment: @funilrys Either or and Mark's answer combined would be the most appropriate way to *answer* the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is rtrim removing more characters, and giving weird output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46307527/why-is-rtrim-removing-more-characters-and-giving-weird-output)

Answer (score 4):

Understand that the second argument to trim functions like rtrim is a set of characters, so you're trying to strip every instance of the characters `s`, `c` and `.` from the end of your string, not an ordered sequence of characters. That's why it also removes the trailing `s` from `vegas` as well.

From the php.net documentation:

> **character_mask**
>
> You can also specify the characters you want to strip, by means of the character_mask parameter. Simply list all characters that you want to be stripped. With .. you can specify a range of characters.

Better test that the end of your string is `.css` and then substring the last 4 characters

Comment: ...and no explicit mention of this on php.net could have been made in the official documentation? -_- Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [basename()](http://php.net/manual/bg/function.basename.php) function:

```
<?php
$file = 'vegas.css';
$file = basename($file, ".css");
echo $file;
```

// Return

```
vegas
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str_replace` to replace the text with empty value:

```
$file = 'vegas.css';
echo str_replace(".css", "", $file);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the following:

echo basename('file.csv','.csv');